# XAML / PowerShell -> array into DataGrid

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, datagrid

I play around with XAML and PowerShell. My quest now it's to speed up to put stuff from a array into a DataGrid.

Here is the current Code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid_DisabledAccounts" Background="#FF616161" Foreground="Black" AutoGenerateColumns="True" SelectionMode="Extended">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="SamAccountName" Binding="{Binding SamAccountName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="distinguishedName" Binding="{Binding distinguishedName}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Now I am using a ForEach Loop to put Values from my Array into the DataGrid.

```
$obj = $null
$tmp = New-Object -TypeName PSObject

$Func_Coll_DisabledAccounts = @()

$Func_DisabledAccounts = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $global:gbl_SrcGroup -Recursive) | Where-Object { -not ((Get-ADUser $_.samAccountName).Enabled) } | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, distinguishedName

ForEach($obj in $Func_DisabledAccounts) {

    $tmp | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $obj.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $tmp | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "SamAccountName" -Value $obj.SamAccountName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $tmp | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "distinguishedName" -Value $obj.distinguishedName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    $DataGrid_DisabledAccounts.AddChild([pscustomobject]@{Name=$obj.Name;SamAccountName=$obj.SamAccountName;distinguishedName=$obj.distinguishedName})
    $DataGrid_DisabledAccounts.Items.Refresh()

    $Func_Coll_DisabledAccounts += $tmp

}
```

It's not possible for me to do something like this:

```
$DataGrid_DisabledAccounts.AddChild($Func_DisabledAccounts)
```

I hope someone knows what I want :)

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Did you try `$DataGrid_DisabledAccounts.ItemsSource = $Func_DisabledAccounts` ?

Comment: Yes I tried. But I didn't get any value into my DataGrid Tables. Just when I use a ForEach. When I using a ListView does it work. But i want a DataGrid :)

Comment: How does the `DataGrid` look like?

Comment: You mean the DataGrid Code? Take a look at the top. I worte it down. Simple DataGrid with 3 Columns with the Header Name of each Value from the array.

Comment: I mean what it looks like on the screen when you are trying to set the `ItemsSource` property. What's the difference between the working `ListView` code and this code?

Comment: ah ok. When I using a List View it display the content from the Array. When I use a Grid View it's just empty. No value is displayed. That was the reason why I am started rewrite it with the ForEach Loop. But it takes a long time.

Comment: Please post the working code the the `ListView`. It has to be some difference.

Comment: Sorry - what button i have to click to post that code without to use 'add a comment'